# Minimizing the react native app without going back

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I navigate normally from screen A to screen B

I want to make screen B as the root of the app / the navigation should ignore screen A and deal with screen B as the root

so in screen B , when the user hit the android navigation back , it should minimize the app
not to return to screen A

here's my code in screen B

```
BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress" , () => {
  BackHandler.exitApp();
});
```

when I hit the android back button

**the actual result**

it minimize the app and when I open it again , it shows screen A

**the expected result**

it should only minimize the app and when I open it again , it shows the same screen B

By the way , it there any method to make a screen as a root instead of putting these many listeners manually and making the things complicated?

In more correct meaning , To change the root screen programmatically , as React Navigation only initialize it and cannot change it later

example

```
const RootNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
     ScreenA : ScreenA,
     ScreenB : ScreenB
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'ScreenA' // I mean here
  }
);
```

What if I want to change this initialRouteName in run-time after the ReactNavigation initialization

Answer (score 0):

I think `useFocusEffect` can help you

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-android-back-button-handling/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set the initialRouteName as a prop it is because there is some data that you need to fetch asynchronously before you render the app navigation. another way to handle this is to use a switchnavigator and have a screen that you show when you are fetching the async data, then navigate to the appropriate initial route with params when necessary. see [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow.html/) for a full example of this.

And this is an open [RFC](https://github.com/react-navigation/rfcs/issues/23)